# How append inside the specific div while I use function getJSON (read file)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the form with id="bah" and within div with id="demo".
I have the problem with append because how i append the datos in demo.
How to correct?
it 's wrong `}.appendTo('#demo);`
how to correct????

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        var p;
    $.getJSON('config_json.cfg', function(data) {
      var items = [];

      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
//      items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
        items.push('<li id="'+key+'"class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>'+val+'</li>');
            p=key;
      });

      $('<ul/>', {
             'id' :'sortable',
        html: items.join('')
       }).appendTo('#demo');

    });

    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();


    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" method="get" id="form1">



<div id="demo">
</div>
<br>
<p>Clicca su <input type="image" src="img/finish.png" value="Submit" alt="Submit"> per inviare il form</p>
<br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`}.appendTo('#demo);` It is correct. try with change  `}).appendTo('#demo');` to  `}).appendTo($('#demo'));`

Answer (score 0):

How about just doing it the old fashion way:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('config_json.cfg', function(data) {
        var items = '<ul id="sortable">';

        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items += '<li id="'+key+'"class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>'+val+'</li>';
        });

        items += '</ul>';

        $(items).appendTo('#demo');

    });

    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});​
```